# Is There A Way to Query Demographic Sourced from Birthdays?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to generate demographic data. I made all separate queries because I could not think of the way to do them at once.

```
from django.utils import timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta # $ pip install python-dateutil

teenagers_count = queryset.filter(birthday__lte=now-relativedelta(years=10), birthday__gt=now-relativedelta(years=20)).count()
twenties_count = queryset.filter(birthday__lte=now-relativedelta(years=20), birthday__gt=now-relativedelta(years=30)).count()
thirties_count = queryset.filter(birthday__lte=now-relativedelta(years=30), birthday__gt=now-relativedelta(years=40)).count()
forties_count = queryset.filter(birthday__lte=now-relativedelta(years=40), birthday__gt=now-relativedelta(years=50)).count()
fifties_and_older_count = queryset.filter(birthday__lte=now-relativedelta(years=50)).count()
```

Is there a way to do this by just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, annotate your age to your queryset, with:

```py
age = ExpressionWrapper(datetime.now() - F('created_at'), output_field=fields.DurationField())
queryset.annotate(age=age) #=> Will add "age" on each records
```

Second, use Case/When to make up your own logic on `age_range` field

```py
queryset.annotate(age=age).annotate(
            age_range=Case(
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=10), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=20), then=Value('teens')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=20), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=30), then=Value('twenties')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=30), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=40), then=Value('thirties')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=40), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=50), then=Value('fourties')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=50), then=Value('fifties')),
                default=Value('Unknow'),
                output_field=fields.CharField(),
        )) #=> This will add "age_range" field on your queryset
```

Third, just aggregate by "age_range".
All together:

```py
import datetime 
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, F, Count, ExpressionWrapper, fields

age = ExpressionWrapper(datetime.now() - F('created_at'), output_field=fields.DurationField())
counts = queryset.annotate(age=age).annotate(
            age_range=Case(
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=10), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=20), then=Value('teens')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=20), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=30), then=Value('twenties')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=30), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=40), then=Value('thirties')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=40), age__lt=datetime.timedelta(years=50), then=Value('fourties')),
                When(age__gte=datetime.timedelta(years=50), then=Value('fifties')),
                default=Value('Unknow'),
                output_field=fields.CharField(),
        )).order_by('age_range').values('age_range').annotate(count=Count('age_range'))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works other than the fact that datetime.timedelta() does not support "years" parameter.